# Arduino pin connection basic

Tags: arduino, led, basic, breadboard, connect

[image]In the Arduino Uno's basic manual, connections for fading led are given. They have connected led on breadboard. The positive of led is connected through a resistor to the pin no 9 (pwm) and negative to the ground (ground of arduino with a wire). There is also a connection of 5V from arduino to breadboard. The led worked fine without that connection too. Is there any use to it? (It is given in the manual)

Comment: Probably not, but can you at least post a link for this manual and what page number you are referring to? or add a picture of the page.

Comment: @Linkyyy added the picture, it is mentioned in the 2nd point, so it has no use!

Comment: @Megh: No that 5V connection has no use. Maybe they used it in the illustration because it is neccessary for the next assignment?

Comment: @Linkyyy Yes, probably for controlling led using pushbutton. Just saw. Thanks.

Comment: Book uses a Fritzing cartoon as a sole source of circuit information.  No schematic in the book.  This isn't the first time I see this in books about RPi and Arduino.  It does a disservice to beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the 5V pin to be connected to the breadboard, maybe this setup is part of a tutorial and 5V will be used in a later part.

Answer (score -1):

It serves no purpose. Pin 9 can provide enough current to power and dim a single led.